# SSRS to SUM only visible rows in a table

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have designed SSRS with a table. My need is only to some visible values of those columns. Like below:

[image: Image Reference is here]

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your criteria for the visibility is:

```
=IIF(Fields!Criteria.Value = "Visible", True, False)
```

So just use the same criteria in your `Sum()` expression for your total. Like this for example:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Criteria.Value = "Visible", 1, 0))
```

It will add `1` for every row in the detail section which meets the condition.

Comment: thanks for your response. But i need to some required output rather than this. That is "Only sum visible values inside/outside group". Please anyone give the answer.....